# Symfony2: login does not work on first try after clearing cookies

Tags: authentication, symfony

When trying to log in, Symfony2 tells me that I provided the wrong credentials. Second try works. Any ideas why this could happen?
To reproduce the behaviour, I have to logout, clear cookies, go to the login page again and log in again.

I am using FOSUserBundle.

config.yml:

```
framework:
#esi:             ~
secret:          asdfsadfasdf
#translator:      { fallback: en }
charset:         UTF-8
router:          { resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml" }
form:            true
csrf_protection: true
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:      { engines: ['twig'], assets_version: v1.2 } #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
translator:      { fallback: de }

session:    
    default_locale:  de
    auto_start:     false
    lifetime:       1000000
...
```

security.yml:

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]


providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    public:
        pattern:   ^/.*
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            check_path: /login_check
            remember_me: true
        remember_me:
            key:      aaasfasdfasdfsadfsadf
            lifetime: 1296000 #15 days in second
            path:     /
        anonymous: true
        logout: true


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
    #- { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
    - { path: ^/events/create, roles: ROLE_USER }
    #...
acl:
    connection: default
```

routing.yml:

```
_imagine:
    resource: .
    type:     imagine

_index:
    resource: "@AjadoEventHubBundle/Controller/IndexController.php"
    type:     annotation

fos_comment_api:
    type: rest
    resource: "@FOSCommentBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /api

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
...
```

@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml:

```
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <route id="fos_user_security_login" pattern="/login">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:login</default>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_security_check" pattern="/login_check">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:check</default>
    </route>

    <route id="fos_user_security_logout" pattern="/logout">
        <default key="_controller">FOSUserBundle:Security:logout</default>
    </route>

</routes>
```

Comment: Try adding the relevant code to your question, "login" in symfony 2 is very abstract.

Comment: @ilanco: let me know if you need more code. I just figured out that I am using a quite old version of FOSUserBundle (6cdd9c292afa219ef799893061eaae1fc400ae33) - will try to update today...

Comment: Could you include the routing part with shows the login routes, if any?

Comment: @RoelVeldhuizen done. Let me know if you need some more info!

Answer (score 2):

On my opinion, this is expected behaviour as you enabled anonymous authentication :

- You request your app url, without being logged => a session cookie is created with your session ID
- An anonymous token is created
- You clear cookie => no more session id to identify you
- Next request, no token is attached to your login request...

Comment: so what would I have to do to get rid of the behaviour? Sorry, I just copied big parts of the security configuration and I don't know the meaning of each LOC :/

Comment: Why would you need to manage the cookie deletion at the login page ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with symfony, however, I have experienced the same problem when the authentication check looked for a valid cookie, but the cookie was being created after the check--thus causing it to pass the second time, never the first.

Comment: Yes. The cookie is obviously being created, _after_ the check is performed.

Answer (score 1):

By default Symfony require that a session must be exist before the submitting of the form

from the docs

> ```
> # by default, a session must exist before submitting an authentication request
> # if false, then Request::hasPreviousSession is not called during authentication
> # new in Symfony 2.3
> ```

In order to over come this you could set "require_previous_session" (which is by default true) to false in the "security.yml" as under "form_login" like this:
require_previous_session: false

You could read more about it in Symfony docs in the following link
[SecurityBundle Configuration ("security")](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I solved it following the answer here [Symfony 2 “Your session has timed out or you have disabled cookies”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694213/8238315).

@AlterPHP was right, you have to login twice because the first time you are getting an error like this:

`Authentication request failed. (...) Your session has timed out, or you have disabled cookies.`

As you don't have a session started, with this request a new session is created. Next time you try to login, as the session was created, you can login.

You had to set the option `require_previous_session: false` in your `app/config/security.yml` file to avoid looking for a previous session:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            form_login:
                require_previous_session: false
```